# python+Opencv imwrite method exception

Tags: python, image, opencv, exception

```
resPath = "result/"+resN+".png"

cv2.imwrite(resPath,resI)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvfSD.png)

this exception occured result to code above
I searched google and found out this exception occurs when I don't write ".jpg" or ".png" extensions but as you see I wrote it but exception occured so I don't know reason why

Also if I change code like this

```
resPath = "result/"+resN+".png"

cv2.imwrite("result/image1.png",resI)
```

there's no problem. if resN is "image1", resPath equals to "result/image1.png" but why
resPath = "result/"+resN+".png"

```
cv2.imwrite(resPath,resI)
```

this code makes exception and

```
cv2.imwrite("result/image1.png",resI)
```

this doesn't?

Comment: This should be helpful for you to understand: https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#write-an-image

Comment: `print(repr("result/" + resN + ".png"))`

Comment: What’s the data type of `resN`?

Comment: resN type is <class 'str'>

Comment: And what’s its value? Maybe you have a double point somewhere...